# What is the execution time for a double multiplication on a 16 bit microcontroller with only multiplication hardware support?

Tags: performance, time, microcontroller

What is the execution time for a double multiplication on a 16 bit microcontroller with only multiplication hardware support? No FPU.

I know it runs through a sequence of code to calculate it.  I'm just not sure how long it takes to run through it.

example

```
double conversion = 0.03039013;
double distance= 10.23456;

double total = conversion * distance;//cost of this line
```

Has anyone timed it?

What is the difference between 64 bit float and 32 bit float multiplication in respects to time? Is there much to gain from using 32 over 64 bit.

Comment: It's exactly 42 clock cycles.

Comment: @Paul How come 42, seems arbitrary.

Comment: Well yes - that was the point - without knowing the CPU or any other relevant details how would you expect anyone to give you a useful answer?

Comment: @Ashitakalax: 42 is a magic number in a popular book.  It's not an actual answer.

Comment: Try it, use a port pin to check the timing on an oscilloscope or logic analyzer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran through a two scenarios, 32 bit float computation and 64 bit computation.  The Platform was on a 16 bit Renesas M16C/28 MCU ( this platform has a multiplier, but no floating point hardware. running at 20 Mhz, 1 cycle = 50 ns.

Note: this was done with software so timing isn't perfect, but the idea and concept is proven in it.

**Scenario 1:**

```
void floatMultiple(void)
{
    float a = 123456.1234;
    float b = 123456.1234;
    float result = 0;
    result = a * b;
}
```

timing in cycles

Best case:  305(15.25uSec)
worse case:  2033(101.65uSec)

**Scenario 2:**

```
void doubleMultiple(void)
{
    double a = 123456.1234;
    double b = 123456.1234;
    double result = 0;
    result = a * b;
}
```

Using the same numbers same system, only changing the type.
Best case:  2356(117.8uSec)
worse case:  14567(728.35uSec)

there is a little overhead with my timing system, I would guess that the overhead is around 100 cycles. due to function calls.

This still shows the significant difference from using a float and a double on a 16 bit MCU.  The difference is about 7 times longer(FOR THIS PLATFORM).

There can be a difference with the generated assembly code to calculate the floating point values on different systems.